# How to select a column from a text file which has no header using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, text

I have a text file which is tabulated. When I open the file in python using pandas, it shows me that the file contains only one column but there are many columns in it. I've tried using pd.DataFrames, sep= '\s*', sep= '\t', but I can't select the column since there is only one column. I've even tried specifying the header but the header moves to the exterior right side and specifies the whole file as one column only. I've also tried .loc method and mentioned specific column number but it always returns rows. I want to select the first column (A, A), third column (HIS, PRO) and fourth column (0, 0). 
I want to get the above mentioned specific columns and print it in a CSV file.
Here is the code I have used along with some file components.

1) After opening the file using pd:

> [599 rows x 1 columns]

2) The file format:

```
                          pdb_id: 1IHV
0      radii_filename: MD_threshold: 4
1    A    20  HIS  0   MaximumDistance
2    A    21  PRO  0   MaximumDistance
3    A    22  THR  0   MaximumDistance
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

3) code:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_table("file_path.txt", sep= '\t')
U= df.loc[:][2:4]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody gets any file like this, it can be opened and the column can be selected using the following codes:

```
f=open('file.txt',"r")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split(' ')[range])
    for w in result:
        s='\t'.join(w)
        print(s)
```

Where range is the column you want to select.